# Opengrok cannot escape anchors on full search

Tags: regex, lucene, opengrok

I am using opengrok at work, trying to match certain anchors in the codebase using regular expressions

From opengrok documentation:

> Escaping special characters: Opengrok supports escaping special
> characters that are part of the query syntax. Current special
> characters are:
> + - && || ! ( ) { } [ ] ^ " ~ * ? : \ /

Since anchors are not special characters my query is as follow:

[image]

lucene fails to parse my query for some reason:

[image]

---

Now when I escape both anchors `/\<property\>*/`, it does not fail but I get 0 results. There are thousands of * text in our codebase. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "<" and ">" characters are not indexed by Lucene (they're not in the index), so they're not searchable.

See more related info [here](https://github.com/oracle/opengrok/issues/688).

Comment: Oh, really? Anything you can link to support this?

Comment: A just added more details in the answer.